# OS X Yosemite Today Widget without Auto-Layout

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite, notificationcenter, ios8-today-widget

I'd like to implement a Today Widget (OS X) without making use of Auto-Layout.

I know that I can control the widget size via `setPreferredContentSize:;`, but whenever I disable Auto-Layout for the XIB of my widget, the widget is simply blank both in the Simulator and in the Notification Center.

I did not find any hints in the docs that there is something special to set up if not using Auto-Layout. Does anybody know what to do to get a non-blank widget?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use auto layout?

Comment: In my case, not using auto-layout would simplify handling the UI a lot.

Comment: What is the ui layout? Maybe the right question is to ask how to use auto layout to get it to work.

Comment: :) What I'm trying to achieve may indeed be simple for Auto-Layout pros: I have a simple webview, which is stretched across the entire widget view controller's view. I did that by pinning the webview's edges to the parent view's edges (leading space, trailing space, etc.). Next, when the user clicks the Settings button (the 'i' in the widget header), an additional settings view must be revealed on top of the main view. So I'd have to increase the widget view's total height, to make room for the settings view, but prevent the webview to grow with it.

Comment: Yep. I can do that. But not atm just on my mobile phone. Will show you how when I'm on my computer. The thing to do is pin the top, left and right of the web view and give it a fixed height. Then pin the setting ui to the bottom of the webview. Now when the superview grows the settings ui will be revealed at the bottom.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks! The last problem would be: based on the settings, the webview will have different heights. Fixing the webview's height would be one thing — but I would have to change the fixed height programatically in code, when the settings changed, right?

Comment: Yes, to do that you have to create a property for the height constraint. (CTRL-Drag into code). Then you can do... `heightConstraint.constant = 100; [self layoutIfNeeded];`

Comment: Great. Also I didn't know I can bind constraints via outlets. That's been one of the obstacles that made me not want to use Auto-Layout :).

Comment: I'd recommend the Ray Wednerlich books iOS 8 by Tutorials. It has 2 whole chapters on Auto Layout and they are brilliant.